# How can I resolve the "Could not find the required component 'libdlib'" error?

Tags: cmake, dlib

I am trying to to compile [this](https://github.com/ipa-rmb/autopnp/tree/indigo_dev/ipa_room_segmentation) ROS package but I get the following error

```
 Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libdlib" with any of the following names:

libdlibConfig.cmake
libdlib-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "libdlib" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"libdlib_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"libdlib" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.
```

Referencing some other answers on SO and elsewhere, I have added the following lines to CMakeLists.txt

```
include(/home//src/dlib/dlib/cmake)
include_directories (${dlib_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(room_segmentation_server ${dlib_LIBRARIES})
```

I have also installed dlib using [these](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-dlib-on-ubuntu/) instructions but the error persists.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: it is way more easy to help you, if you provide your code and the exact error you're facing.
I suppose, that you are trying to find the library with help of `find_package(dlib CONFIG)`?!

`libdlibConfig.cmake` is a CMake-File that needs to be provided by your `dlib` installation. This file has everthing written into it for your cmake, to find the include- and library paths of your `dlib`-installation. With its help, your cmake then sets the Variables that you're trying to use: `dlib_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `dlib_LIBRARIES` (pointing to its corresponding paths).

Therefor that your `cmake`-call complains, that such a `libdlibConfig.cmake` couldn't be found, you either do not have such a file on your system, or it is not in the expected directory. In both ways: the variables that you are trying to use, will not be set. Alternatively there might be a `FindDlib.cmake`-File on your system, that does almost the same, that you could refer to by `find_package(Dlib)`.

If you do not have either of those two file, you need to specify the paths to the include-dir and library-dir on your own:

```
set(dlib_LIBRARIES "<path to your libdlib.dll>")
set(dlib_INCLUDE_DIR "<path to your dlib/include-folder>")
find_library(LIBDLIB dlib ${dlib_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(<your_target> ${dlib_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(<your_target> LIBDLIB)
```